# SingleObserver.onError called on background thread instead of main thread

Tags: rx-java2, reactivex

Well as I understood from the documentation using singel.observeOn(Scheduler) will guarantee that any downstream event will be executed on that scheduler.

Apparently the onError called on the same scheduler that thrown the error as I receiving this error -

```
> Caused by:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke setValue on a background thread
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.assertMainThread(LiveData.java:443)
at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:286)
at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:33)
at com.bonimoo.womlauncher.presentation.wizard.registration.RegistrationViewModel$1.onError(RegistrationViewModel.java:89)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback$FlatMapSingleObserver.onError(SingleFlatMap.java:116)
at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ResumeSingleObserver.onError(ResumeSingleObserver.java:51)
at io.reactivex.internal.disposables.EmptyDisposable.error(EmptyDisposable.java:78)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleError.subscribeActual(SingleError.java:42)
at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
```

out of this code -

```java
public static<T> SingleTransformer<T,T> getSingleTransformer(){
return upstream -> upstream
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}


GetHotelsList getHotelsList = new GetHotelsList(
    AsyncTransformers.getSingleTransformer(), networkRepo);

getHotelsList.getHotels()
   .map(hotels->   
        CollectionsUtil.mapList(hotels,
        RegistrationMappers::mapHotelToPresentationHotel)
   )
   .flatMap((Function<List<HotelPresentation>, SingleSource<List<HotelPresentation>>>) hotelPresentations -> 
        Completable.timer(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .andThen(Single.error(new Throwable()))
   )
   .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<HotelPresentation>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                addDisposable(d);
                RegistrationState currentState = stateLiveData.getValue();
                stateLiveData.setValue(currentState.newBuilder().setLoadingHotels(true).build());
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(List<HotelPresentation> hotelPresentations) {
                RegistrationState currentState = stateLiveData.getValue();
                stateLiveData.setValue(currentState.newBuilder().setHotelsList(hotelPresentations).setLoadingHotels(false).build());
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                RegistrationState currentState = stateLiveData.getValue();
                stateLiveData.setValue(currentState.newBuilder().setLoadingHotels(false).build());
            }
        });
```

and the debugger shown that onError called on RxSchedulerIoThread.

Comment: That's because Completable.timer runs on the io thread and the follow-up error is also emitted there. As you said, `observeOn` specifies where the downstream is observed, but the moment there is another async boundary or scheduled operation, that's no longer guaranteed. Apply `observeOn` just before `subscribe` and that will make sure the `subscribe` receives signals on the desired thread.

Comment: so timer operator does not inherit the observing scheduler?

Comment: Every operator has a **Scheduler** javadoc entry to indicate where it works. [Completable.timer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#timer-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-io.reactivex.Scheduler-) says "Scheduler: timer operates on the Scheduler you specify." So if you specify a Scheduler, how and why would it inherit any other scheduler?